# Neo4J not starting: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized log entry version -9 and logHeaderFormatVersion -1

Tags: neo4j

I am getting following error while running Neo4j.bat on Windows.
Earlier it used to work and I have used it for many hours. But dont know whats gone wrong now. If I recall it correctly, I guess I faced the same issue earlier once, but it vanished on its own automatically. This time I am not able to start Neo4j at all.

```
C:\Mahesh\Program Files\neo4j-community-3.0.0-M05\bin>Neo4j.bat
WARNING! This batch script has been deprecated. Please use the provided PowerShell scripts instead: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/powershell.html
2016-11-28 17:14:53.094+0530 INFO  Starting...
2016-11-28 17:14:55.425+0530 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@59717aa7' was successfully initializ
ed, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@59717aa7' was successfully initi
alized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@59717aa7' was successfully initialized, but failed to
 start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:206)
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:90)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.start(CommunityBootstrapper.java:43)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.main(CommunityBootstrapper.java:30)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@59717aa7' was successfully initialized, but failed to start
. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:178)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, C:\Mahesh\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.0-M\data\databases\graph.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$21(CommunityNeoServer.java:55)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery@42e996ca' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:416)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:505)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:99)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized log entry version -9 and logHeaderFormatVersion -1. At position LogPosition{logVersion=0, byteOffset=454975} and entry v
ersion null
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.LogEntryVersion.byVersion(LogEntryVersion.java:199)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.VersionAwareLogEntryReader.readLogEntry(VersionAwareLogEntryReader.java:87)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.LogEntryCursor.next(LogEntryCursor.java:50)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.LatestCheckPointFinder.find(LatestCheckPointFinder.java:77)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.PositionToRecoverFrom.apply(PositionToRecoverFrom.java:53)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI.getPositionToRecoverFrom(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:110)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery.init(Recovery.java:72)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
        ... 19 more
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:01 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: Params
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:01 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: -Dorg.neo4j.config.file="conf/neo4j.conf"
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:01 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: "-XX:+UseG1GC"
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:01 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: "-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow"
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:01 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: "-XX:hashCode=5"
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:01 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: "-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch"
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:01 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions"
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:01 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: "-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields"
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:01 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: "-XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:01 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source="zip"
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:01 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: Classpath: "-classpath" "...deleted classpath for cleaner post..."
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:02 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: Main class: org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper
Nov 28, 2016 5:15:02 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
INFO: Args:
```

I feel the issue is as pointed out by last `Caused by`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized log entry version -9 and logHeaderFormatVersion -1. At position LogPosition{logVersion=0, byteOffset=454975} and entry version null
```

which is causing main problem. But I am not able to make out any sense out of it. Whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue. Try using the latest dependency for neo4j (3.1.2 version solved the issue for me)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of neo4j are you running this on? I happen to know that log entry version -9 is from a neo4j version 3.0.2. If you've run neo4j on that version or a later patch release of 3.0.x, to then go back to some version before that and try to open that db, this could happen. Is that it?